# Make Angular 12 app run on really old browser

Tags: angular, polyfills, es5-compatiblity

this is my version of Angular:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.6
Node: 16.13.2 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.6
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.6
@angular/flex-layout            12.0.0-beta.35
@schematics/angular             12.2.6
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.2.4
```

I have an Angular app that works fine on the latest version of Chrome and Edge but most of our customers are using IE11, or really old versions of Chrome (ex: Chrome 45).
So I need to make the app compatible with all these browsers.

I tried to solve the issue for IE 11 first.
I initially had a blank page when reaching the homepage of the app.

I've made the following changes :

1. I've changed the `tsconfig` file as follow:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
```

2. I've updated my `polyfill.ts` file as follow:

```js
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
//import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/promise';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

3. I've updated my `browserslist` file as follow

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-10 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

4. I have the follow babelrc file :

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/presets-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      },
    }]
  ]
}
```

With this configuration, in IE 11 I can finally see my login page.
My login page has the following "login" button:

```html
<div>
          <button mat-flat-button [disabled]="!this.credentials.password"
            [ngClass]="{'button-action': this.credentials.login && this.credentials.password}" class=" full-width "
           (click)="alert('lalalalala')"><span class="fs-12 light">LOGIN</span></button>
        </div>
```

1. Do I really need the babelrc file or is it just enough to update the tsconfig file and the polyfill.ts file?
2. Is Angular material not supporting IE11 the reason why `alert` is not triggered on the `onclick` event?
3. I've tried to launch my app with Firefox 42, and I have the following error that I don't understand:

```
TypeError: client.onOpen is not a function
```

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: zone.onStable.emit is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: zone.onStable.emit is not a function
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT : I was able to try / catch the login call and alert the error.
The error is `ReferenceError: crypto is not defined`.
Any ideas?**

Comment: I can understand (though not agree with) IE11 support, but I gotta know, **why** is anyone using Chrome 45? How is that even possible?

Comment: Our customers are really really old people :) and they told us that they couldn't upgrade their browser to the latest version. I've just tried to replace my login call with a simple alert, and the alert is not displayed on the "onclick" event. So I guess it has nothing to do with promise.. I'm using angular material.

Comment: If you need to support obsolete (and insecure...) computers and operating-systems then I think the "best" approach (which is subjective) is to have your users use a VDI accessed over Remote Desktop which runs an up-to-date instance of Chrome.

Comment: as far as i know its only IE11 was only deemed obsolete in angular 13. So i am surprised that side already fail there. Maybe backtrack a bit of configurations and approach it a bit more slowly with the polyfills and target libs

Comment: I also made the experience recently, that the old Firefox 52 stopped working as of Angular 13...